# Unable to deploy virtual-host on Apache2 with Docker

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, apache2, virtualhost

I have an application called "project1" mounted on Docker with the php:5.6-apache image, all running on an Ubuntu mounted virtual box.

I can currently access it via the url `http://localhost/project1`.

I have tried to set up a virtual-host to be able to access it from the url `http://dev.project1.loc` but I am not able to in any way. I have already set up the v-host and hosts file in addition to the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mysql

COPY ./conf/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./conf/apache2/sites-available/dev.project1.loc.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.project1.loc.conf

CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND

RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod mime
RUN a2ensite 000-default
RUN a2ensite dev.project1.loc

RUN service apache2 restart
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
networks:
  local_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config: 
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
services: 
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql-php-5-6
    restart: always
    command: 
      --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ./conf/mysql/conf/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    environment: 
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3306
    networks: 
      - local_network
  php:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php-5-6
    volumes: 
        - ./src:/var/www/html
        - ./conf/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - ./conf/hosts:/etc/hosts
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks: 
      - local_network
```

hosts (copied from the container itself):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost

127.0.0.1   dev.project1.loc
::1         dev.project1.loc
```

000-default.conf (copied from sites-enabled in the container):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

dev.project1.loc.conf (copied from sites-enabled in the container):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@project1.loc
    ServerName dev.project1.loc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1
    <Directory /var/www/html/project1>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the Apache configuration (in apache2.conf inside the container):

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I show you part of my directory structure in local (it is not the same as in the container) to give you an idea of the volumes:

```
- www/html/docker-php-mysql-apache
    - conf
        - apache2
            - sites-available
                - 000-default.conf
                - dev.project1.loc.conf
        - mysql
        - php
        - hosts
    - mysql
    - src
        - index.php
        - Project1
            - index.php
    - docker-compose.yml
    - Dockerfile
```

As much as I have made dozens of tests I have not been able to access through the virtual-host.

I have also tried to delete the 000-default.conf file but the only thing I get is to access directly to project1 through `http://localhost`.

I have also tried to delete the mapping of `127.0.0.1 to localhost` from the hosts file but I can still access through localhost.

I don't know what to do anymore, I have used virtual-hosts hundreds of times in xampp but I am being unable to do it in Docker. This example is tested directly from a tutorial as I have previously tried it with other projects always with the same result.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you need to setup a reverse proxy. I don't fully understand the config myself, but you're looking for `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` virtual host properties. You probably have to edit the `/sites-available/ssl-proxy.conf` and maybe even your `dev.project1.loc.conf` file.